# How do I keep displaying the same clickable suggestions in Dialogflow after I click them once?

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want the chatbot to loop back to the suggestion chips after clicking on any one of them?

Comment: Welcome! Questions on StackOverflow works best when you provide as many details as possible, including what you've tried that hasn't worked, any code you may have used, and any errors you got while trying to do it. Updating your question to include any code you're currently using will help us help you better. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions always disappear after being clicked. That's why you usually want to work with actual buttons if you want to buttons to stay visible. Although this depends on which messaging channel you're working on, generally this is a universal thing that all channels display the same way.